# How to extact multiple specific frames from video which their number is saved in a filename using ffmpeg in linux?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

I use the following ffmpeg command to extract multiple frames from a video.

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.MP4  -vf "select='eq(n\,1315)+eq(n\,1607)'"  -vsync drop "filename%03d.png"
```

However, i would like to save their numbers in a text file eg. 200,500,600, 100 and then use that text file in select option.

How I can do that?

eg.

```
frms=$(cat frames.txt); ffmpeg -i myvideo.MP4  -vf "select='eq(n\,$frms)'"  -vsync drop "filename%03d.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Save frame number in a file one below other.
Then, run sed to make it proper for ffmpeg select command.
and then, run ffmpeg to extract selected frames that will be read from the given file that you have saved them.

```
sed -i 's/^/eq(n\\,/' frm.txt; #adds eq(n\,
sed -i 's/$/)\+/'     frm.txt; #adds )+ at the end of each line
sed -i '$ s/.$//'     frm.txt; # remove + in last line (last digit)
frms=$(cat frm.txt); ffmpeg -i myvideo.MP4  -vf "select='$frms'"  -vsync drop "filename%03d.bmp"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! However, `ffmpeg` continues doesn't stop after all required frames were extracted.

Comment: yeah? in my machine not. maybe you have an old ffmpeg? i work on linux. ffmpeg version 5.1.3-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm using `ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021`.